# Display flex dynamic height mosaic grid

Tags: javascript, css, grid

Issue width display flex and dynamic height. Each element inside the section are dynamic height. If height is not defined in section, each element are just shown in a horizontal list. If height is set on section e.g. 800px, each element will be shown in a beautifully grid. Is there a way to do this dynamic, without using js, but css alone?

Using

**Section:**

```
width: 100%
display: flex; 
flex-flow: column wrap; 
justify-content: flex-start; 
align-content:center; 
align-items:flex-start;
```

**Elements inside section**

```
align-self: auto;
width: 250px;
```

Comment: Any issues with the provided answers?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue stems from the fact that for `flex-direction: column` to work you have to specify a `height` or `max-height` on the flex container.

You have two options:

**1. Using css multi-columns.** http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/95Z5r/3/

```
.grid {
  columns: 250px;
}
```

**2. Setting a (percentage) height on your section.** (http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/Tpb8v/):

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.section {
  height: 75%;
  ...
}
```

I'd recommend you go with css multi-columns: Basic functionality is widely supported (multi-column: [82.93%](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) vs. flex-box [79.47%](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)) and columns appear to be more light-weight for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that flex is going from top to bottom because you have defined `flex-direction` as `column`, not `row`. Then when you don't define a height it will just push the height as much as possible.

I don't think it is possible to find any good solution without Javascript, but the following is one way of doing it in pure CSS.

## CSS solution with multi-column

You have already defined a fixed width, so we can use the [multi-column CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts). The issue with this solution is that div will be following to the next column, so some items will be split in two.

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-column-count: auto;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -webkit-column-width: 50px;
  -moz-column-count: auto;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-count: auto;
  column-gap: 15px;
  column-fill: auto;
  column-width: 50px;
}

#container > div
{
  background-color:#eee;
  margin:2px;
}
```

## Side note: Add new elements (through javascript)

I was interested to see how new elements affected the original layout, so I have [made an example of how items are pushed into the column](http://jsfiddle.net/danschultzer/kF3b8/). You probably want to calculate it better with Javascript because all old items will be pushed to the left column instead of remaining in the same place. The same issue will happen using flex column.